# How to pass 2 parameters from routerLink?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routerlink

I am trying to pass 2 parameters through the routerLink, to my component and then to my service to get the data.

The Html looks like this:-

```
  <h3><a routerLink="['/repository', {{res.owner.login}}, {{res.name}} ]">{{res.owner.login}}</a></h3>
```

and in my component I have the following:-

```
ngOnInit() {
this._route.params
.map(params => params['userName,repoName'])
.subscribe((params) => {
  this.userName = params['userName']; this.repoName = params['repoName']
  console.log('params = ' + params)
  this._githubService.getRepo(params)
    .subscribe(repository => {
      this.repository = repository;
    })
  })
}
```

And in my service I have the following code:-

```
getRepo(params: any){
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
   return this._http.get("https://api.github.com/repos/"+ params.userName +"/" + params.repoName+ "/commits&sort=stars&order=desc&page=1", { headers: headers, withCredentials: false })
      .map(this.extractRepo)
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error, this.router));

}
```

Router configuration is as follows:-

```
   import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
   import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

   import { HomeComponent } from '../app/components/home/home.component';
   import { RepositoryComponent } from 
    '../app/components/repository/repository.component';

   const appRoutes: Routes = [
       {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
       {path: 'repository', component: RepositoryComponent}
   ];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

However when I run the application, the link is being displayed as follows:-

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5B'/repository'%2C%20tetris%2C%20react-tetris%20%5D'
```

How can I format the routerLink and get the parameters to send to my service?

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put routerLink in [routerLink]. Because without the square brackets, its like you are binding to a string, and the string will be `['/repository', {{res.owner.login}}, {{res.name}} ]` exactly this.

So whenever you try to bind something that existing in the class, you need to use []. Example:
`someVariable = 'http://etc..'`
than to bind it, you use `[src]="someVariable"`. If you just do `src="someVariable"` this is not a valid link right, its just a string

Also, it will be useful if you post the router configuration above

Comment: I tried your suggestion Denko :-                    <h3><a [routerLink]="['/repository', {{res.owner.login}}, {{res.name}} ]">{{res.owner.login}}</a></h3>
but I get the following error:- Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 16 in [['/repository', {{res.owner.login}}, {{res.name}} ]] in HomeComponent@19:27

Comment: I also added the router configuration

Answer (score 1):

I finally found my mistake :-

So in my app.routes.ts, I had to change the routing to this:-

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
   {path: 'repository/:userName/:repoName', component: RepositoryComponent}
];
```

Then in my HTML, the routerlink, I changed it to the following:-

```
  <h3><a [routerLink]="['/repository', res.owner.login, res.name ]">{{res.owner.login}}</a></h3>
```

and the component became like this on Julia's suggestion:-

```
ngOnInit() {
   let {params} = this._route.snapshot;
   this._githubService.getRepo(params)
   .subscribe(repository => {
     this.repository = repository;
     console.log(repository);
})

}
```

}

Everything works fine now and I am getting the object back from the service.

Thanks for both of you for your help, which led me in the right direction to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

.map(params => params['userName,repoName']) does not look right.

You can do just

```
let {params} = this.route.snapshot;
this._githubService.getRepo(params)
.subscribe(repository => {
  this.repository = repository;
})
```